# Prestashop mobile number validation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

The mobile number field in prestashop accepts more than 10 numbers..i Just need exactly 10 numbers to be added

How to validate the mobile number field in prestashop while registering a new account???

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `AddressCore` class like this
Create a file in `/override/classes/Address.php`

Copy the `$definition` array from the file `/classes/Address.php` and modify it

```
<?php
class Address extends AddressCore{

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'address',
        'primary' => 'id_address',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_customer' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
            'id_manufacturer' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
            'id_supplier' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
            'id_warehouse' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
            'id_country' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
            'id_state' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId'),
            'alias' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
            'company' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 64),
            'lastname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
            'firstname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
            'vat_number' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
            'address1' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
            'address2' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'size' => 128),
            'postcode' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPostCode', 'size' => 12),
            'city' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCityName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
            'other' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMessage', 'size' => 300),
            'phone' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
            'phone_mobile' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 10),
            'dni' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isDniLite', 'size' => 16),
            'deleted' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
            'date_add' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
            'date_upd' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        ),
    );

}
```

Take a look at the `phone_mobile` line, the size is set to 10

Finally, delete the file `cache/class_index.php` to reload the overrides or empty PrestaShop cache in `Performance`

Using overrides is better than modifying on "original" files because it makes updating PrestaShop in the future easier